# Does "the one" refer to the red book or just a book or are both possible?

Tags: pronouns

1. I don't want the **red book** on poetry, I want **the one** on science.

Does "the one" stand for "red book" or simply "book", or maybe both are possible？Thank you.

Comment: It's difficult if not impossible to come up with a convincing context for anyone to say your cited text. Even if the only choices available were a red book on science and a red book on poetry, why would anyone mention the colour? And if the wanted science book *wasn't* red, you'd have even less reason to mention the colour of the unwanted poetry book. But *in principle*, the construction is ambiguous. Adjectival "red" *might* be thought of as "going along for the ride" with the actual noun ***book*** as referenced by ***the one***. Or it might not. Whatever makes most sense.

Comment: Suppose in a British newsagent's, you say *I don't want yesterday's Guardian, I want The Times.* That might well be understood differently depending on whether you were saying it on Saturday or on Sunday (because there *is* such a thing as The *Sunday* Times, but The Guardian isn't published on Sundays). In practice, though, I expect the newsagent would just ask for clarification.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thank you. I get it.

Comment: **I don't want the red book on poetry. I want the blue one on science**. If you use color to identify the books, well, there you go. You don't have to repeat the word book: I don't want the poetry book. I want the science one. OR the one on science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pragmatics!

It could be either, but in any realistic context there would be no ambiguity.

Why would you say "I don't want the red book ...".  This wouldn't happen in outer space or in an empty white room.  There would have to be you, someone you are talking to, and some books that both you and the person you are talking to can see.

And, apparently, you think that when you say "I want the one on science", then the other person will know which book you are talking about.

If there is a red book on poetry on the desk, a yellow book on art, and a blue book on science and you say:

> I don't want the red book on poetry, I want the one on science.

The person knows that "one" means book.

On the other hand, perhaps the colours mean something.  Perhaps "red" is for grade 1 students, blue is for grade 2 etc.  And you are in a library and there are red books on poetry, science etc and there are blue books on poetry and science.  The librarian knows you want a grade 1 book, and offers you the red poetry book and you say

> I don't want the red book on poetry, I want the one on science.

Then "one" means red book.

How can it mean different things?  It is because language is never spoken without context.

Comment: Extraordinary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in your sentence:

**One** corresponds to **red book**.
**The one** corresponds to **the red book**.

Here is why:

I saw **a notebook**. 
I saw **a red notebook**. 
I bought **the red notebook** with what was left of my salary.
I bought **it** with what was left of my salary.
It's **the one** that I bought with what was left of my salary.

**The red notebook** looks nicer than **my old notebook**. 
**It** looks nicer than **my old notebook**. 
**It** looks nicer than **the one** that I had. *

Comment: You have literally instructed OP to speak the words "One corresponds to red book." I suspect that was not your intent. Furthermore, your explanation is opaque. Those sentences do not speak for themselves.

Comment: To Jeffrey:
That was not my intention as indicated by "I would say". 
Sorry if it was not clear though. 
To be more precise, what I meant was:
In your sentence, "one" corresponds to... and "the one" corresponds to...
Hope it is clearer now. 
As for the sentences not speaking for themselves, let's agree to differ. :-)

Comment: Don't tell *me.* Edit your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, PPH.